# tools:context=".MainActivity" is failing, how can i solve it?

Tags: android

the argument: `tools:context=".MainActivity"` gives me error, addly the part named: `.MainActivity` appears in color red, what can i do?

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

Comment: Do you still have a `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

tried rebuild project or [try invalidate cache restart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgCLX.png)

if still same problem you can add yourpackagename.mainactivity
like in the picture [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbU9B.png)

```
tools:context="com.etest.myapplicwr.MainActivity">
```

my packgae name is com.etest.myapplicwr
replace it with your package name

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it, or you can update it to point to some activity or fragment where you will be using this layout resource.

Answer (score 0):

you should find which folder save your `MainActivity`.
For Example:[image]
So, Check it.

And then, you should understand what's its function.

it is used by: Lint, Android Studio layout editor .

This attribute declares which activity this layout is associated with by default.

This enables features in the editor or layout preview that require knowledge of the activity, such as what the layout theme should be in the preview and where to insert onClick handlers when you make those from a quickfix.

you can find more information [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes)